# Hot questions on StackExchange

Tags: discussion, publicity

I don't know how they compute this list, but at least briefly two questions from Math.StackExchange were on the list of the hotest questions in all of StackExchange: http://stackexchange.com/ . :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has always been 1 to 2 questions on the SE front page from each site, it's not that surprising.

See the question [*How do the “arbitrary hotness points” work on the new Stack Exchange home page?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60756/how-do-the-arbitrary-hotness-points-work-on-the-new-stack-exchange-home-page) on MSO on how the hotness is determined.

Comment: Thanks for that link.  I see now that it is not that surprising.